# Redirecting output of command "systat -ifstat" to a file adding special chars in FreeBsd

Tags: shell, freebsd

I am trying to redirect outputs of systat -ifstat and systat -vmstat to a file and When I open that file, lot of special chars are added to a file like below

```
(B)0[?1049h[1;39r[m[4l[H[2J[1;21H/0   /1   /2   /3   /4   /5   /6   /7   /8   /9   /10
[68DLoad Average

[11DInterface[4;27HTraffic[4;49HPeak[4;69HTotal[2;21H[5;13H1/1  in[6C0.000 KB/s[5;46H0.000 KB/s[5;66H260.087 MB[6;18Hout     0.000 KB/s[6;46H0.000 KB/s[6;66H205.319
```

The command I am using to redirect to a file is below:

```
 systat -ifstat 1 > text.txt
```

Can someone guide me to get rid of these special chars.Help is appreciated.

Comment: I doubt this is a good idea. You'd better find proper way to obtain that information. Try reading `systat` source to find out how it gathers all the info.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that [systat(from the man page)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=systat) display system statistics in a screen-oriented fashion using the curser screen display library, therefore in the try to get something like a screenshot, this partially works:

```
systat -ifstat | tee /tmp/output
```

to see the output like when using the command you will need to do `cat /tmp/output`, otherwise you will see all the shell escape characters.

You could also try `script`:

```
$ script
Script started, output file is typescript
$ systat -ifstat
```

next, you exit systat <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

```
$ exit 
exit

Script done, output file is typescript
```

This will create a file named `typescript` but the output is not as clear as when using `tee`. (still, haven't found a way of how to render properly `typescript` within `csh`)